# How does using CiviCRM compare to using NationBuilder?

Tags: civimail, civievent, civicontribute, civimember, civireport

Have you used or tried out NationBuilder.com, a US-based commercial not-free CRM used for political and community advocacy? What does CiviCRM do better, or worse? I prefer Civi but looking for more evidence for comparisons and info about experiences of those who've used both Civi and NationBuilder. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

never used it directly, but had some customers that switched between civi and nationbuilder, in one direction or the other.

so the thing they liked better on nationbuilder was as well the thing they liked less: the ui is more polished, but/because you can do less. less features, less customisation, so easier to use and maintain.

a friend working for a political party that used it for all their candidates in the latest election said that the integration with social media- eg. from an email address being able to know the twitter or facebook accounts and how many followers and friends was quite nifty... but not always working as well as they hoped.

not sure how your extension compares to that, you're using the same base as they are, aren't you?

Comment: Xavier thanks, using beta of Jon Goldberg's and Joseph Lowery's extension for getting voter district data using the Sunshine Labs APIs. Still on the alpha version of the OSDI API extension.

Comment: Also, the Attentive.ly extension for CiviCRM that Joe Murray and crew are developing does/will allow a lot of the same social media info to populate into Civi contact records. Also need to jump back on trying that out.

Comment: When looking into Social Media integration, you might also be interested in an initiative to integrate CiviCRM with https://zapier.com. Here is a forum thread on this: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35223.0 Might not look that promising, but the topic was further discussed in a working group at CiviCon London, and I think a blog post calling for a joint effort by interested parties might appear any time soon on civicrm.org/blog.