# Can CiviCRM do mass/bulk targeted e-mail "blasts" and "petitions" like Salsa, NationBuilder and other for-profit platforms?

Tags: civimail, civicampaign, civipetiton

Can CiviCRM and CiviMail replace what an organization is doing now with Salsa, NationBuilder  or other for-profit platforms - like send targeted e-mail "blasts" to elected officials, and host "petitions"?

So for example, if an organization's goal is to generate 50 e-mails from CiviCRM contacts in each legislative district to each member of a legislature, with the message "please vote for Bill 1 and support public financing of election campaigns", can CiviCRM do that?

Or, if an organization wants to ask CiviCRM contacts in each district to sign an open petition to each legislator, can CiviCRM do that?

I asked a similar question at [How does using CiviCRM compare to using NationBuilder?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/how-does-using-civicrm-compare-to-using-nationbuilder) but I think an update is worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

It may help if you clarify the criteria around 'email blast to officials' but as I interpret it both 'send an email to an official' and 'sign up to a petition' can both be handled nicely using drupal webform and views.

**Send an email to an official**: will depend how automatically you want the target to be identified, but you could set up a View search, enter your postcode, get back a link to a webform that prefills cid2 to be the email for the designated official, and submission of the form triggers the email with or without the personal message.

**Sign up to a petition**: set up webform with a views block that will show eg 'number of petition signatures' and/or 'latest people to sign up' with a checkbox on the form that would allow users to indicate if they are happy for their name to show on the public roll.

Comment: Pete, thanks, I added examples to (hopefully) clarify the criteria.